# How to create a view of nodes that are referenced by a node that references the current node?

Tags: views, nodes

I have three content types: patient, patient medication, and physician.

Using the Node Reference module, patient medication references the patient content type and the physician content type. How can I create a view with a contextual filter that does the following: When I view a physician node, I want to view all patients that the physician has interacted with. Using the two Node Reference fields in the patient medication content type, how can I display a block of unique patients that the physician has prescribed a medication to?

I basically have it set up like a relational table:
Patient <-- Patient Medication --> Physician  (The arrows represent the node reference)

Answer (score 1):

Create a view of content type Physician and set relationship between 
Patient --- Patient Medication & Patient Medication --- Physician keep both relationship required.
Now add all field related with Patient nodes.
Here only a block display with patient and  Patient Medication.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you clarify what you mean by set a relationship between patient -- Patient Medication & Patient Medication -- Physician? When I try to add a relationship to the view, I can only add one field.

Comment: You can add multiple relationship ,one-by-one

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose that that's your Patient Medication structure:

- Title
- Patient (*field_ref_patient*) (node reference to Patient content type)
- Physician (*field_ref_physician*) (node reference to Physician content type)

So, let's make a view with these settings:

**Fields**

- Patient (*field_ref_patient*) (Relation: Patient)

**Relations**

- Physician (*field_ref_physician*) (The **reverse** version)

**Contextual Filters**

- Content NID (Default value: Content ID from URL)

This might give you the patients of Patient Medication where Physician is the node that you are viewing

I created an example here: http://dfjfp.ply.st/ (you have 24 hours to check it until it die), go to Structure > Views > Physician and give it a node ID, in my example the ID is 3, that id belongs to the Patient Medication that i created.

Comment: So? did you tried that idea?